# Full Screen Background Image Is Stretched

Tags: html, image, css, photoshop

I had made a full screen background image for one of my clients, but the problem is that when I make the image to fit all the screen using the following css codes:

```
#bg-image img{
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
width:100%;
max-height: 100%;
}
#bg-image{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}
```

Everything works perfect, as the image is filling all the background of my home page, but the problem is that now the background image seems to be stretched, and I would like to know how to make my image is size or ratio to be correct in order to fit the whole screen size without getting stretched (with full quality), so that the background image is quality to be perfect.

So, how to make my image to fit perfectly on the background of my home page.

Any Help Would Be Very much Appreciated!

Comment: Here are a few good options, even some that work in IE8. While background-size is great and pretty simple, IE8 doesn't support it. If that is not a factor, then don't worry about it. http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should really look into the [background size](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/) property instead of using fixed images. Using 'cover' for background-size, means that the image should grow or shrink just enough to cover the whole background.

If you know the dimensions of the image. You can use a media query to change the background-size to 'auto' when it would otherwise grow beyond it's original size.

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-image: url(http://leydenlewis.com/images/LANDING_PAGE.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-size: cover;
}
@media (min-width: 1120px), (min-height: 630px) {
    body { background-size: auto; }
}
```

Comment: The background is appearing correctly but the problem is that the image looks so stretched, I want it to appear with high quality and to fit the whole screen (like no scrolling) some how, it is very important to me.I don't know whether I can make this to happen using css 3 or by resizing my image to appear in full quality.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go, just don't forget that IE8 doesn't support `background-size` so you may be leaving a small portion of users out in the cold.

Comment: The problem is that the image is still stretched on my site, I would like it to look 100% in quality.You can see here http://leydenlewis.com/

Comment: @HamzaAbdElwahab Do you mean that you don't want the image to grow. With other words it should be max 1120px x 630px?

Comment: So, I should try to crop the image to 1120px x 630 px ? And will this image look perfect also in larger screens ? I mean should I use some css rules so that a larger image appears for larger screens and smaller images to appear for smaller screen sizes ? So there should be more images with different sizes and this way I guess it will keep the quality, but what should be the size of the images ? And what rules can I use ? I guess you have the perfect answer that I'm looking for.

Comment: @HamzaAbdElwahab Your image is 1120 x 630 px, that why I took those dimensions. The media query causes the image will **not** to grow beyond it's original size. Try this with and without the media query. I'm unsure what you want, but it's bound to be one of those.

Comment: You need to add `body {background-size: auto;}` inside the media-query in place of what you have there.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
#bg-image {
position:fixed;
left:-50%;
top:-50%;
width:200%;
height: 200%;
}

#bg-image img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

This should get you the results you want and work in most browsers as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, this had cropped my image is top and bottom so not all the image is appearing right now.I would like my image to appear 100% in my home page, but with full quality, I dont want it to look stretched.This is a link to my site http://leydenlewis.com/

Comment: Try one of the methods in this link and see if any of them work for you: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: @HamzaAbdElwahab Also, if you want your background image to maintain it's aspect ratio and fill the entire screen regardless of screen size, you will have to crop the image at some point.

Comment: And How should I crop the image, I mean in width or height ? or what should the size be ? I would love to make the background image to is aspect ratio be perfect on all screen sizes if it's possible, it would be great!

Comment: That's what my answer above does for you. It automatically crops the image so that it maintains it's aspect ratio and fills the entire screen at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This should keep the image the correct ratio:

```
#bg-image{
height: auto;
width: auto;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style> 
body {
background: url(http://37.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lusitdffhf1qj5tnlo1_r1_500.gif);
background-size: 320px 600px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-top: 40px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: While this code might help solve the problem, a code only answer is not high quality. A better answer tells what the code does, explains why the approach was taken, shows where the code gets inserted, and links to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Since the questions doesn't specifically state CSS only (or NOT Javascript), here is a jQuery solution that I've worked out and have been using.  I've noticed there might be an issue with mobile browsers.

```
//resize the background image
function resizeImage($selection){
    //get the ratio of the image
    var imageRatio = $selection.width() / $selection.height();

    //get the screen ratio
    var screenRatio = $(window).width() / $(window).height();

    //if the image is wider than the screen
    if(imageRatio > screenRatio){
        $selection.height($(window).height()); //set image height to screen height
        $selection.width($(window).height()*imageRatio); //set the correct width based on image ratio
    }

    //if the screen is wider than the image
    else{
        $selection.width($(window).width()); //set the image width to the screen width
        $selection.height($(window).width()/imageRatio); //set the correct image height based on the image ratio
    }
}
```

Run this whenever you want to resize the image, typically on "onresize" and "onload"

`<body onresize="resizeImage($('#bgImage'))">`

Answer (score -2):

```
#bg-image{background: url(https://unsplash.com/photos/P3IJy9JMsiU/download?force=true) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;}
```

Comment: please provide an explanation on how you solved the issue

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When adding an answer to a six year old question with an accepted answer and five existing answers it is very important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. Code only answers can generally be improved by adding an explanation of how and why they work. Why in this case did you include so many browser specific version of the rule given the current coverage for this CSS rule among browsers. I just checked https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_background-size_contain_and_cover and it looks like there is strong support.