# Perfectly place an image bigger than screens

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am new to CSS and media queries and I have also followed this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254538/full-screen-background-image-is-stretched) but didn't got my problem solved. I have an image which is bigger than the screen resolution. The dimension of image is 1532*933 and the resolution of my desktop is 1366*768. I am trying to make a page in which the image is in the background of the body. I am trying to perfectly fit the image on the screen. So for that I have written this CSS

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
body{
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-image: url("/public/images/image.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0, 0;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px), (min-height: 630px) {
    body { background-size: auto; }
}
```

But I can clearly see that the image is not getting placed properly. It's being cut off from the bottom side and right hand side. I want to place this image properly in the full screen (means `top=0, bottom = 0, right = 0, left = 0`) without losing the quality of image.

Also I am trying to get the image perfectly fit in other resolutions as well using the same image, so I am using media queries.

How can I achieve this ?

Regards

Comment: you can try body { background-size: 100% 100%; } , but image will look like shrinked a little bit

Comment: @charankumar It's same, I didn't see any changes in the background image. Also I don't want to compromise with the image quality

Comment: might be cache then. You can try 100% 100% !important

Comment: @charankumar yea it's okay, but not satisfied with the image quality

Comment: you could cut the image to the specific sizes that you need and display the right image according with the related resolution

Comment: @Matt that's not the way it should works. Basically the image is already been optimised.

Comment: Yup got it, but if you want a specific size for a specific resolution, the best way could be creating each img for each resolution and call them out using the "srcset" attribute

Comment: @Matt it's a bad design by the way. you never develop something for one screen.

Comment: I know @Lokesh, but from your question seems you want something specific for your resolution. Sorry if I got it incorrectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a way to achieve this. My image is perfectly aligning now without any distortion. Here is my code snippet:

```css
.main-background {
 background: url("https://static-fastly.hackerearth.com/static/hackerearth/images/logo/HE_logo.png") no-repeat center;
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.main-content {
    height : 100vh;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<body class="main-background">
   <div class="main-content">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope it could help:

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.bg { 
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/43/Red_flag.svg/1280px-Red_flag.svg.png");

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%; 

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<div class="bg"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many options. If you need this page only on your pc you can edit yuor image with a dedicated application and then use this in your page. If you need a responsive layout you should use several versions of the image that you want to provide as background image and use media queries to choice the right one for your device. Let's say that you have an image called image.jpg (500x500) you can force resizing using height and width but the image will lost its quality. However you can use media queries like this:

```
 /*width and height of an ipad*/
 @media (min-width: 768px), (min-height: 1024px) {
         body { background-image: url("/public/images/image_ipad.jpg"); }
 }

 /*width and height of a Galaxy S5*/
 @media (min-width: 360px), (min-height: 640px) {
         body { background-image: url("/public/images/image_galaxy.jpg"); }
 }
```

Obviously you can play around with media queries a little better choosing only width range so you can say from x width to y width i will use this image and so on. Keep in mind that for this purpose you can use a vectorial image to make things easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) and (min-height: 630px) {
    body { background-size: auto; }
}
```