# How to get images to not stretch during page resize

Tags: html, css

I would like for my image to keep its normal width and height without stretching in the full screen browser. How could this be accomplished?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <img id='mountain' src='img/mountains.jpg'>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#mountain{
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: You are setting a percentage width and a fixed height. Naturally the image will then stretch... Anyway, "normal width and height without stretching" is rather ambiguous. Do you want a fixed size or a fixed aspect ratio?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20254582/11623848

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Comment: No, nothing worked for me unfortunately. Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you are trying to achieve? Do you want the image to remain the same size, or to change size with the page but still remain the same ratio (16:9 for example)?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this attribute.
Try this.Hope it will work.
Good luck

```
#mountain{
    object-fit: contain;
    object-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    max-height:600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are using a combination of absolute sizing units and relative sizing units. Use either pixels OR percentages, but not both together.

If you want the image to stay the same fixed size, use absolute units such as pixels (`px`), or units based on font size (`em` or `rem`), for example:

```
#mountain{
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

If you want it to resize with the screen or its container, but keep the same ratio, use relative units such as percentages (`%`) or view port sizes (`vw` and `vh`), for example:

```
#mountain{
  width: 80%;
  height: 60%;
}
```

Of course, you should base these sizes on your image's aspect ratio and not some arbitrary values.

If you want the image to display with its original height and width, you can choose to not define `width` and `height` at all, which has the same effect as setting them to `auto`, as `auto` is the default value:

```
#mountain{
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#mountain{
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24963492)